# search with mobile : does Google just look in the mobile-optimized websites?

Tags: seo, mobile, responsive-webdesign

When someone searches a keyword by mobile, does Google search in desktop version of all websites and find the proper result and ***then*** prioritize them according to the responsiveness or mobile-optimizing stuff etc ***OR*** it just search in the mobile version of the mobile-optimized websites ?

I want to create a website with a responsive design, I was wondering that if I should care about SEO in mobile version of the website, or just try to optimize the desktop version for search engines and just care about the design of the mobile version ?

Comment: If its a responsive site, wouldn't that mean the onsite content is the same for mobile users as it is for a desktop user?

Comment: @max- not necessarily, the content can change, many images, texts, ads etc can be smaller, or even hide in mobile version

Answer (score 1):

Google would look at both styles, have look here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com

Check the "Crawl Errors" section in the "Google webmaster", there you will see if there is any error in "Smartphone" tab.

[image: Google Webmaster]

It means that Google cares about your mobile style.

Comment: I know Google cares, I wanna know that if it looks at the desktop version for mobile results or at the mobile version (the content is different)

Comment: This answer shows that Google's crawlers fetch the page multiple times with different user agents: desktop, smartphone, and feature phone.

Answer (score 0):

Oh heck! Where to begin? Responsive design has no bearing on SEO. Do your SEO work as you should. The fact that you have a responsive design does open it up so that your site is available to mobile devices in a usable format. There may be a reordering for mobile enabled sites in the SERPs when searching from a mobile device, but that is not really SEO. It is just the last link in the chain. SEO and making your site mobile friendly are two separate efforts with almost no overlap.

Comment: you mean when someone searches something with his mobile, it is possible that some of the results may not be mobile-optimized, or even have a terrible view on mobile ? I don't think so ...

Comment: Yes. I get mobile users all the time.